# Which Maven Dependencies to Include for Spring BlazeDS Integration?

Tags: spring, maven, blazeds

How can I use Maven to configure BlazeDS AMF services with Spring? Obviously, I can’t just drop jars in my /WEB-INF/lib directory; I have to include the necessary dependencies, but many of the tutorials that exist refer to older versions or non-Maven projects. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The pom.xml in the spring-flex-testdrive/testdrive project has all of the dependencies needed for the Spring BlazeDS Integration.  You can get the spring-flex-testdrive from the [Spring BlazeDS download page](http://www.springsource.com/download/community?project=Spring%20BlazeDS%20Integration) (just the regular Spring BlazeDS distribution).

Comment: Thanks! Here's hoping they get BlazeDS Integration and the Flex add-on for the latest version of Spring Roo to work soon!